# .local/bin' which is not on PATH. Linux subsystem for Windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

in Windows/Linux subsystem/ubuntu/windows power shell/bash:
`pip3 install --upgrade pip`
ok but:
`WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.8 are installed in '/home/chills/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.`

How to put it on path?

---

tried:
`~/.profile`got: `.profile: Permission denied`

tried `vim ~/.bash_profile`
document opens i put in `PATH="$HOME/chills/.local/bin:$PATH"` don't know how to exit, just closing windows power shell..problem remains.

Comment: Remove the quotes.  Also.. you can also use the ~/.bashrc

Comment: 1..bashrc: Permission denied
2.remove quates like that from this? PATH=$HOME/chills/.local/bin:$PATH
tried, but how to save it i guess, and how to exit it, ctrl x doing nothing.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas no need to remove the double quotes from that assignment. `PATH="$HOME/chills/.local/bin:$PATH"` is perfectly acceptable

Comment: Yes, @roaima .. perfectly acceptable.. and pointless.

Answer (score 0):

> tried: `~/.profile` got: `.profile: Permission denied`

The error message is shown because you tried running the file as if it were a program, which it isn't. You're supposed to open it through a text editor, not run it directly.

> tried `vim ~/.bash_profile` document opens i put in `PATH="$HOME/chills/.local/bin:$PATH"` don't know how to exit, just closing windows power shell..problem remains

Closing the window will exit the editor but *will not save* the document.

In Vim, press Esc to leave "insert mode", then input `:wq` to save&exit.

Try `nano` (Ctrl-X) or `micro` (Ctrl-Q) for a more familiar text editor.